# Ordering properties in JSON string (Confused with "Avoiding Class properties to arrange in alphabetical order when instantiated")

Tags: c#, list

I have a class QuarterlySales which I use in my Services which is consumed by a WebApplication which displays the data on a line chart

```
public class QuarterlySales
{
    public string _TimePeriod { get; set; }
    public double _Printer { get; set; }
    public double _Mouse { get; set; }
    public double _KeyBoard { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the Properties are arranged in an alphabetical order when the class is instantiated

[image: sales Object of class QuarterlySales]

The "printer" should always be the first in the series of values displayed on chart but is pushed to the last alphabetically, is there a way I can avoid the class arranging the properties in order?

---

Edit 1: 
Realized its not a problem with Class ordering its properties, but with the JSON object ordered alphabetically that is causing the problem. And its just a co-incidence that both Class properties and JSON results were arranged alphabetically that led to the confusion.

I have assigned Property Order as per @jpgrassi's suggestion

```
public string QuarterlySalesData()
{
    DataTable dtSalesData = new DataTable();
    string returnJsonString = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        List<QuarterlySales> salesList = new List<QuarterlySales>();
        dtSalesData = accountObject.GetSalesData();

        if (dtSalesData != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtSalesData.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                QuarterlySales sales = new QuarterlySales();
                sales._TimePeriod = dtSalesData.Rows[i]["TimePeriod"].ToString();
                sales._Printer = Convert.ToDouble(dtSalesData.Rows[i]["Item1"].ToString());
                sales._Mouse = Convert.ToDouble(dtSalesData.Rows[i]["Item2"].ToString());
                sales._KeyBoard = Convert.ToDouble(dtSalesData.Rows[i]["Item3"].ToString());
                salesList.Add(sales);
            }
        }

        returnJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        return returnJsonString;
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class QuarterlySales
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public double _Printer { get; set; }    

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public double _Mouse { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public double _KeyBoard { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public string _TimePeriod { get; set; }    
}
```

---

Edit 2:
I was constructing the Series Object and removing underscores from the Data I was passing from Services, but since it was Serialized, I wasn't able to loop it

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
   dataforChart = result;
   replaceLoop(dataforChart);
   chartSeries = [];
   var parentKey, childKey = [];
   for (parentKey in dataforChart) 
   {
       if (dataforChart.hasOwnProperty(parentKey))
           for (childKey in dataforChart[parentKey]) 
           {
               if (childKey != "_TimePeriod") 
               {
                   chartSeries.push(
                   {
                       field: childKey,
                       name: childKey
                   });
               }
           }
           break;
   }
   createChart();
   $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
}

function replaceLoop(dataforChart) {
       for (var chartFields = 0; chartFields < dataforChart.length; chartFields++) {
           dataforChart[chartFields]._TimePeriod = dataforChart[chartFields]._TimePeriod.replace(/_/g, ' ');
       }
```

In order to loop, I had to parse the JSON string back to Object

```
dataforChart = JSON.parse(result);
```

Thank you very much @jpgrassi for guiding and following up with the solution, I have marked your solution as an answer!
Thanks everyone for comments and pointing out some mistakes which I will surely correct.

### Updated on 02/26/2016

Instead of all the confusion that the Class alters the properties dynamically or setting the JSON order, I modified the code to generate a dynamic list on the fly which works for any DataTable schema (any number of columns) which doesn't require a custom type (QuarterlySales in this case) to be created. Wanted to update and share.

```
public string QuarterlySalesData(string chartType)
{
    DataTable dtPerformanceIndicator;
    string JSONData = string.Empty;
    accountObject.GetSalesData(chartType, out dtPerformanceIndicator);
    var myList = ToDynamicList(dtPerformanceIndicator);
    JSONData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
    return JSONData;
}

private object ToDynamicList(DataTable dttoDynamicList)
{
    var dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dttoDynamicList.Rows)
    {
        dynamic dynamicObj = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (DataColumn dtcolumn in dttoDynamicList.Columns)
        {
            var dictionaryofValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)dynamicObj;
            dictionaryofValues[dtcolumn.ColumnName] = dtrow[dtcolumn];
        }
        dynamicList.Add(dictionaryofValues);
    }
    return dynamicList;
}
```

Comment: Class properties do not have any specific or guaranteed order. What "chart" are you talking about, the debugger popup?

Comment: Why does the order in which the debugger displays the properties matter?

Comment: The debugger makes it easier to debug properties by sorting them alphabetically. It doesn't affect your actual app code!

Comment: The Services returns the JSON object which I bind to a Kendo UI line Chart. "Printer" appears at the last in the Y-Axis fields which should not be the case.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/legend-sort-order-issue

Comment: offtopic but public properties starting with underlines -> uglyyyy

Comment: you return this data as JSON to your Web App?

Comment: It's just a coincidence that both your JSON serializer and Visual Studio sort the properties alphabetically. You won't solve the JSON issue if you get the debugger to stop sorting them, .

Comment: Again, a type's properties have no defined order. If your acutal question is _"I get a JSON object which I parse to instances of a class which I then feed to a chart, how can I change the order of these properties on the chart?"_, then the answer is _"consult the chart's documentation"_. If it's actually the other way around, so you have an object that you wish to serialize into JSON, then see @jpgrassi's answer.

Comment: I do agree CodeCaster that it should have been "Consult the chart's documentation" and my bad I was taken over by the co-incidence which C.Evenhuis mentioned. Working on @jpgrassi's solution.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Is this QuarterlySalesData method an actual Action in a Controller? Did you debug to see if returnJsonString is ordered correctly? I reproduced your code and it's working on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specified which type of application you are working on (ASP.NET MVC, Web API) I will answer this using a Web API example.

But first, don't depend on properties order. There's no way you can be sure any order will be maintained, your software shouldn't be tied to this kind of requirement.

Using [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm), you can mark your class properties with the `[JsonProperty(Order = x)]` attribute. Taking your necessity of property _Printer always be the first for example:

```
public class QuarterlySales
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public double _Printer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string _TimePeriod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public double _Mouse { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public double _KeyBoard { get; set; }
}
```

This will reproduce this JSON (calling via POSTMAN):

```
{
    "_TimePeriod": "2",
    "_Mouse": 10.1,
    "_KeyBoard": 22,
    "_Printer": 20.2
}
```

**EDIT:** If you are not working with Web API, you can add reference to JSON.Net in your project and use the **JSON.Net serializer** to insure the data will be serialized using the Order Attribute. There's several ways to do this but to keep it short you can do this:

```
List<QuarterlySales> list = new List<QuarterlySales>();    
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //populate list
    list.Add(sales);
}

//Insure the use of the JSON.Net serializer
return = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Comment: Hey @jpgrassi, Its a ASP.NET web application with certain Kendo UI charts. I did use the "JsonProperty" ordering for properties as you mentioned but it isn't working, still it is ordered alphabetically as { "_KeyBoard": 22, "_Mouse": 10.1, "_Printer": 20.2, "_TimePeriod": "2"
}  I'm using a generic list List<QuarterlySales> salesList. Am I missing something?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC? Probably the JSON.NET serializer is not being used to serialize your json. Instead, the default one is. Post your code where you are trying to return the json.

Comment: List<QuarterlySales> salesList = new List<QuarterlySales>();    
for (int i = 0; i < dtSalesData.Rows.Count; i++)
{
 QuarterlySales sales = new QuarterlySales();
 sales._TimePeriod = dtSalesData.Rows[i]["TimePeriod"].ToString();
 sales._Printer = Convert.ToDouble(dtSalesData.Rows[i]["Item1"].ToString());
sales._Mouse = Convert.ToDouble(dtSalesData.Rows[i]["Item2"].ToString());
sales._KeyBoard = Convert.ToDouble(dtSalesData.Rows[i]["Item3"].ToString());
salesList.Add(sales);
}
returnJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesList, Formatting.Indented);
return returnJsonString;

Comment: Post your code in your question please, with proper formatting Just edit it. What you do with returnJsonString? If you are already using JsonConvert.SerializeObject than it should be working.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble! I have edited my question accordingly. Thank you!